# Accessing an array element or return an empty string

Tags: ruby

When the following regular expression match yields no matching captures, accessing the element [1] will return the following error:

```
"".match(/(abc)/)[1]
```

returns the following error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Is there a more concise single line implementation to perform the equivalent?

```
result = "".match(/(abc)/).nil? ? "" : "".match(/(abc)/)[1]
```

I am looking for a solution that does not require having to repeat the matching code `**"".match(/abc/)**` and yet safely access the first captured group or fail with an empty string as result.

[edited to be clearer]

For the following string, the match will be "123":

> "abc123def".match(/abc([0-9]*)/)[1]
>   => "123"

and "abcdef" should return ""

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) with regular expression as an argument.

```
""[/abc/]
```

For the example given:

```
"abc123def"[/(?<=abc)[0-9]*/]
#⇒ "123"
```

Comment: `String#[]` is always presumed to be for things like substrings but it's also quite flexible.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. But:"abc123def"[/abc([0-9]*)/]
=> "abc123"

"abc123def".match(/abc([0-9]*)/)[1]
=> "123"

Comment: Please see a comment: you are using a wrong regexp there.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @MarkKang you can also pass the index of a capture group as the second argument to `String#[]`, e.g: `"abc123def"[/abc([0-9]*)/, 1]`